# Does dust hurt acoustic guitar?

Tags: guitar, maintenance

I usually play guitar regularly, and I always put it on its stand but sometimes due to college work I can't play for a few weeks in between. And what happens is a layer of dust accumulates on my guitar. Does dust hurt acoustic guitar? Its wood the sound? Any things I should be worried about?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about children or animals knocking it off. Or direct sunlight on it for hours. Once it's in its case, there's no need to dust or polish it before playing. Dust won't affect it, but why leave it out? How much effort is involved in using the case? Does it even have a case? If not, why not?

Comment: I don't have children or animals in the house nor is it located where direct sunlight shines. I have a gig bag, but I leave it on the stand next to my study desk because I don't like the idea of putting away the guitar, even if I'm taking a break from it. Furthermore, putting it in the gig bag and getting it out can be quite inconvenient (Since I've put the gig bag in a plastic bag to avoid it accumulating dust as well, I'd have no idea how to clean it). But I take it that your answer is that, dust does not affect acoustic guitar?

Comment: If you care about your guitar,  you won't think of keeping it in the gig bag as "inconvenient."  There are lots more things than just dust to worry about, such as solarization,   things getting dropped on it,  spilling a beer on it,....

Comment: I think someone who talks of spilling "a" beer, or  their primary concern is not dropping anything on the instrument. (being reckless enough to bring fluids or carry things recklessly around the instrument) don't get to talk about other people's "care" for theirs. If you are not going to be helpful and divert from the original question please don't comment at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - a bit of dust is not one of the things that will damage the guitar or affect the sound. Even if you left it sitting in a dusty house for years, and built up a thick layer of dust, I'd still be more concerned about humidity changes, temperatures, sunlight as @Tim mentioned etc.

Most of my guitars are not in cases (I do not have enough room to store them all in cases, so they are all on stands or hanging on walls) and all I do is brush off the dust if I come to play one I haven't picked up for a few weeks.

Comment: The problem for me isn't the guitars - all over seven walls - but their cases! The loft is literally full of them - along with several keyboard cases, spare amps, extra drums, etc. etc. Need to find a better storage idea... +1.

Comment: Yup - I have them in the attic and under beds. At least most of my amps and cabs are in the garage, my music room, and my daughter's room... But that's a good problem, right :-)

Comment: It's when your daughter keeps asking 'Dad, does every little girl have to sleep on 2 4x12s, or am I just special?'

Comment: Hahahahaha - in that case tell her she is very special and privileged :-)

Comment: @Tim  build a wall-sized box with giant glass doors & hang all your axes in that!

Comment: @DoktorMayhem, your answer is exactly what I was searching for endlessly. Thank you.